# How to display image from domain folder in subdomain

Tags: php

I need help on how to display image from a folder on a domain directory to a subdomain. I am on m.domain.com/user but i want to display user images on www.domain.com/user so i don't have to make duplicate. The folder structure is like this:

- home
- public_html/user
- public_html/m/user

This is the code on www.domain.com/user.php

```
$profile_pic = '<img src="user/'.$u.'/'.$avatar.'" alt="'.$u.'">';
```

What am I to write in m.domain.com/user.php to access images on this same directory at www.domain.com/user?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use the absolute URL: `www.domain.com/users/...` there is no obvious way to access the parent directory, to the outside world m.example.com and example.com are completely separate entities.

Comment: I read the question title and all I could think is "How do you get a folder *inside* a file anyway?"

Comment: I have updated my question,  sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use absolute url for images

```
$profile_pic = '<img src="http://example.com/user/'.$u.'/'.$avatar.'" alt="'.$u.'">';
```

Comment: I did that already before asking the question. Thats why I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

In the `src` attribute just write `src="http://www.domain.com/users/'.$u` etcetera.

Comment: Yeah exactly but its not working. Let me check again.

Comment: You accepted the answer so it works? Don't forget the http:// because otherwise the browser treats it (correctly) as a path, e.g. http://m.domain.com/www.domain.com/users .

Comment: The problem is actually from my playbook browser that refused to update changes. I cleared browser cache and its ok now.

Answer (score 0):

or just step outside the current directory into the parent directory using

../  in ur path as many times as its neeeded for example:

```
<?php

include "../Global_Assets/Includes/Subscription_Widget/index.php";
?>
```

providing they are in the same directory on the web server otherwise you would need to use absolute paths IE: http://www.example.com/

Comment: I tried it, Still not working. I know about ../ Something might be wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste the string after 'echo' the $profile_pic? If I'm not mistaken you need a leading slash.

```
$profile_pic = '<img src="/users/'.$u.'/'.$avatar.'" alt="'.$u.'">';
```

**And I think you also missing a trailing "s" of users.**